# VBA search for string in document and check its color

Tags: string, vba, search, colors, ms-word

I tried to make a function to search for a string in a document and check what is the first char in the string that is colored in red.

for example I know that my document contains the string "bread water juice peach wine". Imagine that the bold text is red colored. I want the function to return the int 19 (first red char - p).

```
 Function check(stringToCheck As String) As Integer
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Content

With oRng.Find
    ' to ensure that unwanted formats aren't included as criteria
    .ClearFormatting
    'You don't care what the text is
    .Text = stringToCheck
    'Loop for each match and set a color
    While .Execute
        MsgBox (oRng.Text)
        For i = 1 To 40
'take the Nth char of the string an check if it's red
'the following msgBox is working
MsgBox (Mid(oRng, i, 1))
If Mid(Orng, i, 1).Font.Color = wdColorRed Then
'the following msgBox is not working which means the error is in the last line.
MsgBox ("made it")
check = i
Exit Function
End If
Next i

    Wend

End With


End Function
```

every time I try to call the function I have the error "run time error 424 - object required".

I added some msgboxes to see when is the function interrupted and added a comment in that place.

what is the problem? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing's first: Use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of your module. You'll quickly find that your code has compilation issues.

Do you mean to use `oRng` or `myRange`? This should be consistent.

Once you've done that...

`Mid(myRange, i, 1)` returns a string, not an object.

You may want to use `If oRng.Characters(1).Font.Color = wdColorRed Then` instead.

Here's your code modified that returns correctly:

```
Function check(stringToCheck As String) As Integer
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Content
Dim i As Integer
With oRng.Find
    ' to ensure that unwanted formats aren't included as criteria
    .ClearFormatting
    'You don't care what the text is
    .Text = stringToCheck
    'Loop for each match and set a color
    While .Execute
        MsgBox (oRng.Text)
        For i = 1 To 40
'take the Nth char of the string an check if it's red
'the following msgBox is working
MsgBox oRng.Characters(i)
If oRng.Characters(i).Font.Color = wdColorRed Then
'the following msgBox is not working which means the error is in the last line.
MsgBox ("made it")
check = i
Exit Function
End If
Next i

    Wend

End With


End Function
```

Comment: @Amos I've completed my answer. There is a `Characters` property of the `Range` object that lets you do what you want.

Comment: Wow, thanks! but I think you meant characters(i) and not characters(1).

Comment: @Amos Ah, yeah, sorry. Also, you may want to consider adjusting your loop from `1 To 40` to `1 To Len(Characters)`